# DirectX Orbital Inclination of a sphere

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to make a model of the solar system in Direct X. The problem I am having is getting the orbital inclinations of the planets to appear correctly. The following is the order in which I manipulate the planets:

- Scale
- Rotate
- Axial Tilt
- Translate
- Orbit
- Orbital Inclination

I have also tried:

- Scale
- Rotate
- Axial Tilt
- Translate
- Orbital Inclination
- Orbit

I have stored the data for the orbital inclination (ie Mars has a orbital inclination of 1.85 degrees).

When I apply a rotation to the Z or X axis, the planet just moves up, and rotates above the sun, not in a orbit relative to the x axis.

Comment: The first combination should be correct, if the parts are defined as follows: Orbital inclination is a rotation matrix about the z-axis. Orbit is a rotation matrix about the y-axis. Translate is a translation matrix along the x-axis. Is this the case?

Comment: Can you post that as the answer so I can accept it please? I was doing the orbital inclination around the X axis..... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment the matrices should be the following:

- `Orbital inclination` - a rotation about the z-axis
- `Orbit` - a rotation about the y-axis
- `Translate` - a translation along the x-axis